# How can I make this jQuery more succinct?

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery and would like some pointers on my following block of jQuery code, I'm interested in writing better code.

Basically, the code just slides content in from the left when you click on one of two menu items and then on a further click slides it out. I guess I'm trying to combine it into one code block rather than two functions.

```
$('#menu-item-91').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("Clicked");
    //$('.about').css('display','inherit').slideDown(3000);
    var sliding = $('.sliding');
    var sliding1 = $('.sliding1');

    if( sliding.css('display') == "none" && sliding1.css('display') == "none" ) { //show it
        sliding.fadeIn(0);
        sliding.animate({"left": 0},800);
    }else if ( sliding.css('display') == "none" && sliding1.css('display') == "block" ) {

        sliding1.animate({"left": -300},500 );
        sliding1.delay(500).fadeOut(0);
        sliding.fadeIn(0);
        sliding.animate({"left": 0},800);
    } else {

        sliding.animate({"left": -300},500 );
        sliding.delay(500).fadeOut(0);
    }

});

$('#menu-item-17').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("Clicked");
    //$('.about').css('display','inherit').slideDown(3000);
    var sliding = $('.sliding1');
    var sliding1 = $('.sliding');

    if( sliding.css('display') == "none" && sliding1.css('display') == "none" ) { //show it
        sliding.fadeIn(0);
        sliding.animate({"left": 0},800);
    }else if ( sliding.css('display') == "none" && sliding1.css('display') == "block" ) {

        sliding1.animate({"left": -300},500 );
        sliding1.delay(500).fadeOut(0);
        sliding.fadeIn(0);
        sliding.animate({"left": 0},800);
    } else {

        sliding.animate({"left": -300},500 );
        sliding.delay(500).fadeOut(0);
    }

});
```

That's it! This is my first post so I hope I haven't broke any rules and someone out there can help me be better!

Regards
Tom

***EDIT***

Thanks Guys! Didn't want to mark an answer just yet as I think I probably missed out a bit of detail that's relevant for some of the answers.

The two classes .sliding and .sliding1 are added to separate divs - one called portfolio and one called about.

So the idea is that if you click the about menu item the about div slides in, then if you were to click the portfolio menu item then the about would slide out and portfolio would slide in. But if no items were displayed then the item you clicked would slide in.

Hope this clarifies things, some of the answers just slide in the same content when either menu item was clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: Do both blocks do the same thing? If so then just put a class on each element and activate the jQuery on the class rather than the individual IDs. That would cut your code in half to start with.

Comment: I would cache **sliding jquery variables** outside your click callbacks so they are not created each time you make a click

Comment: Let me understand this, if any of the menu is clicked and none of the slider is visible, then the 'slider' is shown... Am I right?

Comment: @user2008945 yes, that's right. I just edited the question to make more sense hopefully.

Comment: ok.. then check mine or Ricardo's answer. They do the same things only Ricardo has used different names than mine :-p

Comment: Honestly my indentation/terseness/readability is better :)

Comment: @ Ricardo, yah.. but I myself could not say that, you understand :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things you could do here:

- Make use of jQuery's `:visible` selector instead of checking for css display value of 'none'
- Chain your methods on the same element together on one line rather than adding them on separate lines
- It looks like the only differences between the two click functions are the elements they're called on, so instead maybe use a single click function with a comma separated list of selectors

Here's an adapted version of your code:

**Edit** I've added a function that you can call and pass in the selectors for the two sliding variables based on comment feedback from Ricardo below:

```
$("#menu-item-17").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleSlider($(".sliding1"), $(".sliding"));
});

$("#menu-item-91").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleSlider($(".sliding"), $(".sliding1"));
});

function handleSlider(sliding, sliding1)
{
  if (!sliding.is(":visible") && !sliding1.is(":visible"))  //show it
  {
    sliding.fadeIn(0).animate({"left": 0},800);
  } 
  else if (!sliding.is(":visible") && sliding1.is(":visible")) 
  {
    sliding1.animate({"left": -300},500 ).delay(500).fadeOut(0);
    sliding.fadeIn(0).animate({"left": 0},800);
  } else {
    sliding.animate({"left": -300},500 ).delay(500).fadeOut(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: put the var sliding = selector outside of click handler

Comment: If you notice, in #menu-item-91 handler sliding is .sliding and sliding1 is .sliding1 but in #menu-item-17 it's the opposite, so this won't work

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues You're right Ricardo but I believe my question wasn't entirely clear; edited it now.

Comment: So this does the same for both the clicks.

Comment: @NimChimpsky , now why has he used three functions, I wonder!

Comment: @toomanyredirects why did not you just up vote Ricardo's answer, it would have saved you lots of edits :p

Comment: I'm sure it would have, but why leave a broken answer? No harm in correcting mine too.

Comment: Thanks @toomanyredirects. I got yours to work but there were a couple of edits, you called handleSlider on the function handleSliding, and there is no need for the closing bracket ')' on the actual function. For some reason the other scripts wouldn't work, I don't know whether it was an issue with the way the selectors were passed but it worked correctly the way you passed them to the function. Any ideas why?

Comment: No worries @Tom glad it works for you - have fixed those two points - written without testing :-S

Comment: Constantly going to the DOM to retrieve $(".sliding") and $(".sliding1") is bad. Also there's an error, handleSlider($("sliding1"), $(".sliding")); the first selector is looking for an element sliding1 not an element with a class sliding1. How could this marked as correct?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see here is that most of your code is duplicate, and that has nothing to do with jQuery itself, it's a DRY issue. Make use of both :visible and :hidden pseudo classes that jQuery provides and wrap your common code in one place and also make use of chaining to avoid repeatedly using the variable name over and over; last but not least, use $ prefix on jQuery object variables, so they can instantly stand out as such:

```
var $sliding1,
    $sliding2;

function doSlide($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1.is(':hidden') && $item2.is(':hidden')) { //show it
        $item1.fadeIn(0)
             .animate({"left": 0}, 800);
    }
    else if ($item1.is(':hidden') && $item2.is(':visible')) {
        $item2.animate({"left": -300}, 500)
             .delay(500)
             .fadeOut(0);
        $item1.fadeIn(0)
             .animate({"left": 0}, 800);
    }
    else {
        $item1.animate({"left": -300}, 500)
             .delay(500)
             .fadeOut(0);
    }
}

function fetchSliders() {
  $sliding1 = $sliding1 || $('.sliding');
  $sliding2 = $sliding2 || $('.sliding1');
}

$('#menu-item-91').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchSliders();
    doSlide($sliding1, $sliding2);
});

$('#menu-item-17').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchSliders();
    doSlide($sliding2, $sliding1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I can see the logic here and everything looks correct. However, when I click a menu item nothing happens?

Comment: Just edited my answer to do it properly. Lazy load the slidings, so no accessing the DOM without needing to. It's the best way you can do it

Answer (score 0):

using multple id selectors, but you could use a class instead.

```
 var sliding = $('.sliding');
 var sliding1 = $('.sliding1');

$('#menu-item-91, #menu-item-17').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (sliding.css('display') === "none" && sliding1.css('display') === "none" ) { //show it`enter code here`
        sliding.fadeIn(0)
               .animate({"left": 0},800);
    }else if (sliding.css('display') === "none" && sliding1.css('display') === "block" ) {
        sliding1.animate({"left": -300},500 )
                .delay(500)
                .fadeOut(0);
        sliding.fadeIn(0)
               .animate({"left": 0}, 800);
    } else {
        sliding.animate({"left": -300},500)
               .delay(500).fadeOut(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function slideThis(sliding,sliding1)
        {
             if(sliding.is(":visible"))
             sliding.animate({"left": -300},500 ).delay(500).fadeOut(0);

             else 
             {
                 if(sliding1.is(":visible"))
                 sliding1.animate({"left": -300},500 ).delay(500).fadeOut(0);

                 sliding.fadeIn(0).animate({"left": 0},800);
             }    

        }


    var sliding = $('.sliding');
    var sliding1 = $('.sliding1');

    $('#menu-item-91').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        slideThis(sliding,sliding1); //notice the changes in parameter name
    });

    $('#menu-item-17').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        slideThis(sliding1,sliding); //notice the changes in parameter name
    });
```

Comment: why create 3 functions, when one is enough ?

Comment: Where did you see three functions, I could see only one.

Comment: you have two click handlers, and one slideThis function, thats definitely 3

Comment: Did I misunderstood, th menu-91 is opening/closing slider and the menu-17 is associated with slider1? So I thought this was necessary.